# Changing the color of cell editing style action button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can we change the default green color of + image that comes when we set the cell editing style to UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert? I want to set it to blue color.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those icon (`+` and `-`) cannot be modified. If you really find ways to modify the behavior of UITableViewCell, I will appreciate you. One way I think is to implement a custom tableview controller and a custom cell inheritted from UIView, but it is a hard work.